# Microsoft Windows Store: What are these installer parameters and switches?

Tags: electron, windows-installer, exe, microsoft-store

I created a Windows desktop application using Electron.js. I am trying to put it on the Microsoft Windows store. As I am filling out all of the details, the store is asking me for some things that I know nothing about. Specifically, it is asking me for:

Installer parameters
(Provide any switches required for silent installation, such as /s, specific to your installation package.)

and

Installer handling*
(Provide URL for documentation for all miscellaneous EXE return code values.)

My problem is the fact that I don't know what the store is talking about. My installer for this app is a simple setup.exe file. A user simply runs the file on their computer and it should install. I don't know whether or not it installs in "silent mode" (or what silent mode even is when it comes to installing). I also don't know what these "switches" are. You do not install this app from the command line. You just install it using the exe file.

Also, how am I supposed to find out what the return code values for the errors would be?

Has anyone uploaded an app on the Microsoft Store that could possibly help me?

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem, did you find any solution by now? Stupid Microsoft...